# AngularJS $location router and GET PArams - BEST PRACTISE?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i use [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) with the [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) component for my Single-Page Website.

If i want to switch to another view (*path*) and add params, i can use [$location.path()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location) and $location.search() in combination like this:

```
$location.path('/foo/bar/').search('q','foobar');
```

Now i also need to generate Urls (*i.e. to fill links on my site or to offer deep-link-here-directly links*). So i have a service that generates and provides Urls based on user-input and state params.

Normally i would have the service provide something like `/foo/bar/?q=foobar`, but then every time i want to set such a link with $location i would have to use string manipulation to strip away the GET params, call the original path and add the rest in .search().

```
var url = '/foo/bar/?q=foobar'
var tmpUrlParams = url.split('?')[1].split('&');
$location.path('url.split('?')[1]');
for (var i=0;i <= tmpUrlParams.length; i++){
  $location.search(tmpUrlParams[i].split('=')[0], tmpUrlParams[i].split('=')[1]);
}
```

Is there a better solution for this? Well i know there is ... but what is it?

Comment: What if  you have your service provide an object with several properties - fullUrl, baseUrl, and searchParameters -- that way you can use the fullUrl property for making the deep link but you can use the baseUrl and searchParameters when you need to manually switch to another view

Comment: @JoseM sounds good. Not the established Best Practise i was looking for but definately a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but why can't you just use the `url` method on `$location` since it will correctly interpret your query string parameters?

```
//Calling $location.url()
$location.url('/somepath?foo=bar');

//Will result in these values
$location.url(); // '/somepath?foo=bar'
$location.path(); // '/somepath'
$location.search(); // '{"foo":"bar"}'
```

Here is an [interactive jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/8ZrZh/) you can use to play with and see the various values of the [`$location` api](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location) for yourself.

Comment: I couldn't use the url method because ... i did not RTFM ;-) 
Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @AndreschSerj - Best. Comment. Ever.